# Adobe Kuler Themes - meaning/role of 5 colors in a web page

Tags: adobe

The Adobe Kuler website gives a wide range of themes.  Each theme is composed of 5 colors.  Is there any reason/meaning for each of those five colors, based on how it can be used? Something like the first color for text, second color for background, etc....